# How to solve this Import error for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, intellij-idea

I get this error when I try to import *pandas* after installing it using pip install and I'm using *IntelliJ*

> ```sh
> C:\Users\Start\venv\Pyhon3.7\Scripts\python.exe D:/PYTHON/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Start\venv\Pyhon3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
>     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
>   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
> ```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ```sh
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/PYTHON/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py", line 25, in <module>
>     import pandas as pd
>   File "C:\Users\Start\venv\Pyhon3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
>     "the C extensions first.".format(module)
> ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm

1. Go to settings.
2. Go to Project: (Project-name)
3. Go to Project Interpreter and all the modules you have downloaded. Maybe pandas was not installed correctly

Please check if the python version you are using is also 64 bit. If not then that could be the issue. You would be using a 32 bit python version and would have installed a 64 bit binaries for the pandas library.
You can also go to [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to find any python libs.